# Installing Pillow for Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, 64-bit, 17.04, libraries, python-2.7

I want to install Pillow library for Python 2.7 in my Ubuntu 17.04 x64. But however their [official documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html) says, `We do not provide binaries for Linux. Most major Linux distributions, including Fedora, Debian/Ubuntu and ArchLinux include Pillow in packages that previously contained PIL e.g.`

Is there any other way to install it?

Comment: How about `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-pil` ... https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety-updates/python-pil